# SQL: 2 distinct counts with different where clauses on same field

Tags: mysql

How do I combine the 2 queries below into a single query?

```
select count(distinct user_id) as action_1_count, date  
from table    
where action = "action_1"  
group by date;

select count(distinct user_id) as action_2_count, date
from table  
where action = "action_2"  
group by date;
```

Comment: Do you want them as two columns or two rows?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this to merge above query:

```
SELECT date,
         CASE WHEN action  = "action_1" THEN COUNT(user_id) END AS Action1Count,
         CASE WHEN action  = "action_2" THEN COUNT(user_id) END AS Action2Count
  FROM table    
  WHERE action IN ("action_1", "action_2")
  GROUP BY date
```

Comment: this returns values in 1 column per row, with the other column (action1 or action2 depending on row) displaying a null value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), date
FROM table
WHERE action IN ('action_1', 'action_2)
GROUP BY action, date
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to select 2 count(user_id) columns. the first which counts action 1 occurrences, the second which counts action2 occurrences

Comment: @user1601130 Right, add `action` after `SELECT` ... `SEELCT action, COUNT...`

Answer (score 0):

your query can be like this

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), date FROM table WHERE action IN ('action_1', 'action_2') GROUP BY date
```

Here is the other way to use `SUM()` function this should do the trick

```
SELECT 
  SUM(action ='action_1') count_1,
  SUM(action ='action_2') count_2, 
  SUM(action ='action_1' OR action ='action_2') `full_count`,
  date 
FROM
 table 
GROUP BY date
```

Using `SUM()` with expression will result in a boolean that is if `action ='action_1'` then result will be 1 and if not then 0 and this all be summed and produce the count based on the expression result

Answer (score 0):

The above answers will give you multiple rows for action_2, whereas it looks like you only want one row for action_2.

You could use a union:

```
select '1', count(distinct user_id), date
from table
where action = "action_1"
group by 3
union
select '2', count(distinct user_id), max(date)
from table
where action = "action_2"
group by 3;
```

Comment: Although, looking over your original SQL, it's not clear whether or not there's a simple omission.